# Why should your code not use 100% CPU?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu, usage

I'm speaking specifically about a C# .NET 4 program running on Windows XP or higher, but general answers are also acceptable.

Assume an already optimized and efficient program. The problem here is entirely down to effects of high CPU usage on hardware, and whether a high-usage program should be throttled to reduce wear, not on whether my implementation is efficient.

A colleague today suggested that I should not aim for 100% CPU utilization on my data load processes because "modern CPUs are cheap and will degrade quickly at 100% CPU".

Is this true? And if so, why? I was previously under the impression that 100% CPU usage was preferable for an intensive or long operation, and I couldn't find any respectable sources on the subject either way.

Comment: Are you using actual modern CPU's with multiple cores, or very cheap single-core cpu's?

Comment: We have to expect our clients to be running cheap hardware I guess. Minimum supported resolution is still 1024x768 after all.

Comment: Assuming that your application is the only thing running on the box, then strictly speaking, 100% CPU utilization isn't actually bad, but rather, it may indicate that there is something you could maybe do better.  I haven't worked much with desktop apps, but for web apps, for example, I have never seen an application that max'ed out the CPU load and the code using those cycles was truly optimal.  There is always something wrong.  However, that is because on the web, we are often I/O bound, so a CPU problem seems inappropriate.  I'm sure your app is different.

Comment: Also, different operating systems handle this case differently.  My Windows box, for example, runs terribly if the CPU is 100% utilized.  On the other hand, I have seen a Linux server run at 100% CPU for several days straight and it was fine.  (Though we did release a fix a few days later.)

Comment: You want to do work as fast as possible while not being overly wasteful. If you use 100% of the CPU to do useful calculations then it is good. If you use 100% of the CPU in useless loops it is a waste.

Comment: I am not fitted to answer this, but I want to share my view point: Modern CPU's can take quite a pounding. They have many built-in protections for high thermal conditions, and now even the motherboard's and os's have also protections against high system temperature. If you go over 100% too much for instance, on my old Athlon TF-20, the mobo will simply turn all computer off on your face. No wear on the cpu itself, but it's a nice security measure!

Comment: You paid for all of it. Use all of it.

Comment: Raymond Chen's take on the Subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/03/10097861.aspx .  100% CPU usage is fine, as long as it's at the right priority and is accomplishing useful work.

Comment: The question really is not about whether your code uses "*100% of the CPU*" because ***all*** code uses 100% of a CPU core when it is using CPU. Rather, the question is better asked *how long* will it run requiring some high% of an available CPU core? A program that runs once a day and uses 100% CPU for ten seconds should be fine on any platform. But one that runs every 60 minutes and uses 55+ minutes of CPU every time may be a different story. So the real question should be "*How long at 100% is too long?*"

Comment: @BrianHooper - Mr. Pr sid nt! W must mov  at onc to clos th  Lett r   Gap!

Comment: *Very* related from Electronics.SE [Electromigration, are computers nowadays less durable?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/90648/35419) and SuperUser [What is the impact of running the CPU at 100% for long periods at a time?](http://superuser.com/q/431309/220438) and [Is it okay to have 100% CPU usage constantly?](http://superuser.com/q/294238/220438) and [CPU usage at 100% for several hours](http://superuser.com/q/185662/220438) - [this search](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=Electromigration) is a good read.  Key word: Electromigration

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronics and not about programming.

Comment: Would this issue not be related to programming too? Is it not something every programmer should keep in mind if it were an issue?

Comment: @NickUdell - No because it fails the "as a programmer" test.  Tacking "As a programmer" doesn't make the question specific enough to programming to make it on-topic for the site.  Programmers.SE is about conceptual programming questions and not about electronics.

Comment: @NickUdell - and your comment to JensG of `My question was actually about hardware wear and tear from CPU usage` indicates you're more interested in the electronics side of this question than the modest connection to programming.  And in that same comment, you indicated that you were downvoting an answer that focused only on the programming side.

Comment: @GlenH7 Agreed, but programmers need to know the answer. I think the question should stay.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If cooling is insufficient, the CPU might overheat. But they all (well, at least all modern PC CPUs) feature various thermal protection mechanisms which will throttle the clock speed or, as a final resort, shut down.

So yes, on a dusty laptop, 100 % CPU load could cause temporary problems, but nothing will break or "degrade" (whatever that means).

For CPU bound problems, 100 % CPU load is the right way to go.

As for application (UI) responsiveness, that's a separate concept from CPU utilization. It's entirely possible to have an unresponsive application that uses 1 % CPU, or responsive application that uses 100 % CPU. UI responsiveness boils down to amount of work done in the UI thread, and the priority of UI thread vs. other threads.

Comment: and the OS may even enforce a cool down slice for the cores

Comment: I think the real answer is that most processes are not CPU bound, but instead are I/O bound, that's generally why we live in a world where 100% CPU usage is abnormal, at least for "general/generic" computation.

Comment: @windfinder I would say, for "computation", achieving 100% is quite standard, but only as long as "computation" has to do something with maths :) for instance processing MySQL queries is not computation to me ;)

Comment: @tohecz - In the sense I used it computation just means CPU time.  We're just bickering on terminology here, to me everything the CPU does is computation (it "computes").  As a data scientist I'll also say that most maths are also I/O bound (beyond the most trivial math).  A lot of your time in the math(s) world is finding a way to efficiently compress/stream data to your processor in order to keep that CPU usage as high as possible (while minimizing cache inefficiency, of course).

Comment: @windfinder I know the generally accepted meaning of the word, it's just that I don't like it. And depending on what type of math you do, you can easily achieve 100% CPU usage. I do quite often in combinatorics since my programs often have only couple MB of data and one run through the data takes tens of seconds, and at each moment, the program works only with a very small amount of data.

Comment: @tohecz - I totally see your point in that it's easy to confound my usage of the term "computation" here to mean mathematical computation, which is actually the one thing that processor might be able to run at 100% for.  That said, I think it's actually much harder than you are implying to keep your CPU actively working at 100%.  In the case of your combinatorics problems you'd have to start looking at how you could stream a theoretically infinite series of these problems to a CPU while still keeping usage at 100% (you'd also have to look out for false 100% usage, like spin-locks).

Comment: "nothing will degrade" - your performance will degrade.

Comment: @immibis: Please clarify.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Do you have any literature on that? (Or keyword that will work in Google)

Comment: Anecdote re "dusty laptops": for my Master thesis experiments, I've used a then-4-year-old laptop as a runner. **24/7 100% CPU utilization for about 3 months**. After that, said laptop was relegated to server role **for 4 more years** before ultimately giving up the ghost (probably due to an already-damaged graphics issue).

Comment: Actually... yes [it *will* degrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration). And the rate of degradation is such that, for a silicon chip, it (very roughly) takes half as long to fail for every 15°C temperature increase. But whether it matters in practice to a software developer is a different question.

Comment: @romkyns: Fair point. But as [the Electromigration Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration) says, _when operated within the manufacturer's specified temperature and voltage range, a *properly designed* IC device is more likely to fail from other (environmental) causes, such as cumulative damage from gamma-ray bombardment._

Answer (score 16):

There is generally nothing wrong with a program using 100% CPU *while it is actually doing useful work and is not taking time away from anything more important*.  If a particular hardware platform is e.g. only capable of using 100% CPU continuously for one second before it has to throttle back to 50% to avoid overheating, it is generally better for an application *which has useful work to perform* to run as fast as it can, and let the CPU or OS handle any necessary throttling, than for an application to guess how fast it "should" run.  If an application or thread has low-priority work to do which would be useful but not at all time critical, it may be helpful for the OS to limit low-priority-task CPU usage to 50% so that if the CPU needs to do something quickly it will be ready to "sprint" for a second, but the application shouldn't worry about such things beyond requesting a low thread priority.

The biggest situations where it's bad to use 100% CPU are when either:

- The application is busy-waiting for some event which isn't going to be hastened by persistent polling [and might actually be delayed if the effort wasted checking whether the task is done occupies CPU resources which could otherwise be spent *doing* the task].
- The application is redrawing the display excessively often.  The definition of "excessively often" will depend in some measure upon the nature of the display device and the content being shown.  If display hardware can display 120fps, there may be cases where animation could be shown at 120fps without adding motion blur, but could not be shown cleanly at lower frame rates without adding it.  If rendering a frame with motion blur would take much longer than rendering it without, then rendering at 120fps on hardware which supports it could actually be no more costly than rendering at a slower frame rate with motion blur. [Simple situation: a wheel with 29 spokes, rotating at one revolution per second.  At 120fps, the wheel would appear to rotate with the proper speed and direction; at 60fps, a flickering wheel would appear to rotate slowly in the opposite direction].

The former is clearly recognizable as bad.  The second is a bit more subtle.  If one is targeting a mobile platform, it may be desirable in some cases to allow users to select the desired animation frame rate, since some users may not be worried about battery life but would want the best quality animation, while others would accept lower quality animation in exchange for better battery life.  Rather than having the application try to guess where the trade-off should be, it may be helpful to let the user customize it.

Answer (score 15):

Windows programs (winforms/WPF) should at all times stay responsive.
With a naive implementation of a process that uses 100% cpu resources it's all too easy to make your program or even your system seem sluggish and hanging.

With a good implementation (for instance: use a seperate thread with lower priority) it shouldn't be a problem.

You shouldn't worry about your cpu breaking sooner.

Comment: Of course programs doing long-term computations should probably not be winforms/wpf applications but instead batch jobs with no UI. That makes them simpler as they don't need to care about having responsive UI thread and allows launching them via task scheduler and such. If UI is needed, I would still recommend launcher application in completely separate process (that can remain responsive quite easily; it's enough to avoid blocking wait for status message from the batch job).

Answer (score 11):

*"modern CPUs are cheap and will degrade quickly at 100% CPU".*

I don't think anyone's actually addressed the "degrade" part of this question. ICs will degrade when the **die temperature** exceeds the manufacturer's limits. ICs are usually designed to operate up to 125C, although [every 10C increase shortens life by 50%](http://www.academypublisher.com/ijrte/vol02/no08/ijrte02081821.pdf)

Processors didn't always have thermal regulation. Then some AMD Durons experienced problems (allegedly it was possible to destroy one if run without heatsink). Now all PC processors will have builtin temperature sensors that feed back into the CPU clock, and will slow down the clock to prevent damage. So you may find that your program is using 100% of available CPU but the CPU is only running at 75% of its rated speed because its cooling is inadequate.

Within a user program is not the correct place to try to manage CPU consumption. Generally your program should alternate between doing things as fast as possible and waiting, suspended, for input or disk access. You should avoid busy-waiting and spinlocking if possible, but as a courtesy to the rest of the system.

Both Windows and Linux have CPU "govenor" systems that will do performance and thermal management. Because this is done at the OS level it can account for total system CPU consumption. It is the responsibility of the operating system to manage the hardware and prevent user programs from misusing it. It is the responsibility of the hardware *owner* to keep the fans clean and working, and the manufacturer to fit adequate heatsinks and fans in the first place.

There are a few cases where devices have inadequate cooling, but a flood of returns teaches the manufacturers not to do that.

Comment: That video of the exploding AMD Duron is likely fake. Your statement about thermal regulation is still valid.

Comment: Hm, I've taken it out as I can see quite a lot of claims on google that it was fake.

Comment: It's possible to overheat a modern Intel Core CPU by writing code that pushes the SSE engine and deliberately disabling CPU throttling in the OS. It seems that manufacturers (even Intel themselves) design thermal requirements based on the assumption that it's not normal (possible?) to force the CPU to calculate the claimed 4 flops per clock cycle all the time. When someone actually manages to write code that does it his CPU starts overheating. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389648/how-do-i-achieve-the-theoretical-maximum-of-4-flops-per-cycle/8391601#8391601

Comment: ^"allegedly it was possible to destroy one if run without heatsink" -- *I've "personally confirmed" it was possible to destroy earlier K7's without a heatsink..*; that's like, almost 2 decades back?!!

Answer (score 3):

> "..modern CPUs are cheap and will degrade quickly at 100% CPU".

You don't have to worry about "CPU degradation" at all. Modern CPUs are not of less quality than in former times.

It is *very* expensive (and is getting more expensive every couple of years) to make CPUs, some billions to build a new fab are not uncommon (see link).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_fabrication_plant

The production costs of a CPU depends at most on the no. of units produced. This is a well known fact in economy. That's the reason they can be sold (relatively) "cheap" after all.
(I think, no link necessary here)

I can list a number of reasons why I would consider modern CPUs to tend to be of more quality than in "former times".

But only the most important: Advantages in testing. Modern electronics are "designed for test". Whether software or hardware, the broad insight of valuing tests over nearly everything else, is not so old.
For CPUs, the tests are even taken for forming the different price and frequency types, e.g. the best CPUs are sold with highest frequencies. Despite that, the cheaper processors are very often able to operate with higher frequency than sold- they are crippled only for the reason that the manufacturer wants to sell some "high level" processors with higher prices.

(One the other hand, of course there are more errors possible for a processor with more than 1.5 billion transistors as normal nowadays than with some thousand transistors of a processor of the seventies. But this does not contradict to my answer IMO. Processors in general tend to have *many* known errors, at least in microcode, but this is not subject here.)

There are even **more** reasons not to worry about CPU degredation for your program:

- First reason is that modern CPUs decrease their frequency or throttle, if they are getting too hot.

  It should be clear that if you utilize the CPU 100% 24/7 the whole year it will normally die earlier than a CPU only used every second week one hour. But that is true for cars, too, by the way. Only in such cases I would think about CPU utilization and potential sleeps yourself.
- Second reason is that it is really very hard to write a program which uses 100% of the CPU from OS, (e.g. in Windows). Besides, modern CPUs (normally) have at least 2-4 cores. So a traditional algorithm which tends to use 100% of a single core CPU, now has only 50% on a dual core CPU (simplified but seen in real scenarios).
- Moreover the operating system has the control over the CPU and not your program, so if there are other applications with same or higher priority (what is the default), your program is only getting as much CPU as possible, but the other applications will not starve. (Of course this is only the simplified theory, and of course the multitasking of Windows, Linux and others is not perfect, but overall I would consider that for true).

> "I was previously under the impression that 100% CPU usage was
> preferable for an intensive or long operation.."

Yes, stay with this. But for example, if you do waiting&looping for another process, in other words doing nothing, it would be not too bad if you Thread.Sleep() some milliseconds in that loop, giving extra time to others.
Whereas it is not necessary for a good multitasking OS, I solved some issues with this e.g. for Windows 2000. (That does NOT mean of course to use Sleep() in calculations for example..

Comment: While this answer is true today, there is concern for the future.  It used to be that "solid state" meant utmost reliability, but now we have MLC flash that is in some cases only rated for 1000 erase cycles per block.  How long until shrinking die sizes yield a similar phenomena for CPUs that need to run at 100% constantly?

Comment: @Michael, CPUs are not mutating though, and they write to volatile memory—but still I understand your what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 3):

To play the devil's advocate: In a way, a program that cannot reach 100% utilization could cause worse wear: Unless it is suspended waiting for a keystroke, chances are that it is suspended waiting for disk I/O most of the time. And disks are (still usually) big mechanical devices that are subject to mechanical wear or the risk of shock/gyroscopic effects when they move, not to mention power consumption.

Comment: In this case it's simply a complex process on a large (in-memory) dataset, which takes a few minutes. But it's definitely a good point for other readers.

Answer (score 3):

Such degradation is theoretically possible and is called "[electromigration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration#Practical_implications_of_electromigration)". Electromigration is temperature-dependent, accelerating as the temperature goes up. Whether it is a practical problem for modern CPUs is up for debate. Modern VLSI design practices compensate for electromigration and chips are more likely to fail for other reasons.

Having said that, electromigration **happens even at normal loads and temperatures**, but it is slow enough that a well-designed chip either becomes obsolete far before failing, or it fails via another mechanism first.

The rate of electromigration depends on the chip temperature, with the lifetime doubling for every (very roughly) 10°C. This is, in fact, the basis of a test called "HTOL" (high temperature operating life), which measures how long it takes for a chip to die at, say, 125°C. A chip running at 125°C will fail roughly 100 times faster than a chip running at 55°C, so if designed to last at least 10 years at 55°C, a chip might fail within 1 month at 125°C. If running at something more reasonable like 85°C, such a chip would still fail at least 5-10x sooner than it was designed for.

Of course, CPUs are usually designed with higher temperatures in mind, so they can typically last for years at 85°C 24/7 100% load operation. So I would suggest that you don't worry about "wearing out" the CPU, and only worry about whether a 100% load is appropriate from the software engineering perspective.

Comment: Finding that word lead to a search with [many results](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=Electromigration) that are good reading across the SE network... many of which are in Electronics.SE and SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your code on clients, 100% CPU utilization means that client computers in that time cannot be used for anything else but tasks with higher priority. As most applications usually run in default priority, users using those computers will notice computer freezing and will be unable to do ought else on their computers. 
Even if we are talking about short bursts, users working on something will still notice it.

As others said, you were pretty secretive about the setup, so I cannot say for sure. But, if your clients are desktop computers, stay away from 100% CPU utilization. Not because of CPU degradation, but because it is not good form to disrupt users during their work.

Comment: _Windows_ work this way. In Linux and many other systems threads that waited on something (user input) automatically get priority over threads using up their allocated time, so the interactive programs remain responsive even when you don't play with priorities.

Comment: @JanHudec Windows actually does that to. http://superuser.com/questions/194223/does-the-windows-scheduler-allocate-equal-length-quanta-to-threads

Comment: @NtscCobalt: Yes. What does apparently not is Windows CE. And Windows have serious problems whenever a process is heavy on disk, but that's obviously something different (disk handling is rather poor in Windows in general).

Answer (score 1):

So the situation is this: You have some code that runs say for five hours using 100% of all CPUs, that is optimised as much you can, the owner of the machine is fine with the machine being unusable for five hours, and your colleague claims it would be better to run your code in 6 hours using 83.33% of all CPUs, because it puts less wear and tear on the computer.

It depends on the computer that you are using. I know that a computer manufacturer refused warranty repairs within the warranty time on cheap home computers that were used in a scientific setting running 24/7. They clearly wanted the customer to buy their more expensive servers or "business" computers. Whether they were successful, I don't know.

Every Mac that I've owned has at some point in its life run code at 100% CPU usage for days at a time. In one case I had to turn the display off, because I didn't have the original charger for a laptop, and with 4 cores and hyper threading it used more power than the charger supplied - so the battery went down, and when it reached 5 percent the computer slowed down the clock speed until the battery was up to 10% ! (With the display turned off it ran at full speed for several days). In no case, any ill effects.

So with a well-designed computer, you are right. With a badly designed, cheap computer, your colleague might be right. On the other hand, you might consider the cost of your waiting time vs. the cost of buying a replacement computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, make your code a lower priority task, and make sure to keep the CPU-heavy thread separate from the GUI. Then you might have 100% utilization, but the user can always still run other tasks and stay responsive. By itself, a CPU is designed to stay running at 100% usage for a while, or it would not get released. Unless the end user has made serious and dangerous modifications to their hardware, you can't damage anything.